# How to set a variable to false if at least one element in a loop returns false?

Tags: javascript

The following function loops through an object's values. If the value is empty `this.hasInvalidValue` is set to `true`, if it's not empty `this.hasInvalidValue` is set to `false`:

```
user: {
  email: '',
  password: ''
}

function validate () {
  for (let key in this.object) {
    const isValueInvalid = !this.object[key]
    if (this.isKeyRequired(key) && isValueInvalid) {
      this.hasInvalidValue = true
    }
    if (this.isKeyRequired(key) && !isValueInvalid) {
      this.hasInvalidValue = false
    }
  }
}
```

There's a problem with this. Consider a login form:

```
Email // empty (this.hasInvalidValue is set to false)
Password // not empty (this.hasInvalidValue is set to true)

// Final value of this.hasInvalidValue is true. Good

Email // not empty (this.hasInvalidValue is set to false)
Password // empty (this.hasInvalidValue is set to true)

// Final value of this.hasInvalidValue is false. Not good
```

How can I do it so `validate` sets `this.hasInvalidValue` to `false` if at least 1 value is `false`. And to `true` only if all values are not empty?

Comment: as soon as you find an invalid field you can use a `break;` statement to break out of the for loop since there is no need to check the rest of the fields.

Comment: What is `this.object`? Please make your question more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
function validate () {
  this.hasInvalidValue = true
  for (let key in this.object) {
    const isKeyInvalid = !this.object[key]
    if (this.isKeyRequired(key) && !isKeyInvalid) {
      this.hasInvalidValue = false
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks about right except the OP doesn't want `validate()` to return `true` or `false`, he wants to set `this.hasInvalidValue` to `true` or `false`.